# jQuery Alert message looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following jQuery script. This is to alert user when they leave an empty input element.

```
function checkEmpty(elem){
 $(elem).focusout(function (){

if(!$(elem).val() || $(elem).val()==" "){
    alert("This Field can't be empty");     
    return true;
}
});
}
```

Calling in HTML like

```
onclick="checkEmpty(this);
```

If i left the input element blank at first time, it gives only one alert.
But when i leave same input element blank more than one time i am getting continues alert message .
I use the debugger to see what happens, it looping again and again.
Where i went wrong?

Comment: where is the onclick event attached?

Comment: it should be onclick="checkEmpty(this)";and why are you checking it onfocusout thats the reason its getting called in a loop

Comment: is it on the input element? I think you should not use "onclick", since you want to call `checkEmpty` whenever the input element goes out of focus.

Comment: @AkshayJ because i have to alert user when user leaves the element blank, other than `focusout()` what will be possible

Comment: Instead of onclick you can use onblur="checkEmpty(this)" and write the funciton which will only check for empty input. Don't bind focusout inside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function checkEmpty(elem)
{
  if(!$(elem).val() || $(elem).val()==" ")
  {
    alert("This Field can't be empty");     
    return true;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

Enter your name: <input type="text" onblur="checkEmpty(this)">
<p>Write something in the input field, and then click outside the field to lose focus (blur).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are binding the `focusout` event each time the source element is `clicked`. The handlers keep on adding on each click and you need only once. Instead of binding click event handler bind `onfocusout` directly.

*Binding*

```
onfocusout="checkEmpty(this);
```

*Handler function*

```
function checkEmpty(elem){
  if(!$(elem).val() || $(elem).val()==" "){
    alert("This Field can't be empty");     
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nothing work at all :( The function is not triggering

Comment: Can you add related html?

Comment: It's a big HTML coding, created by some developer, i am doing some alteration on it.
FYI: there are `onchange`, `onKeyUp`,` onMouseDown` also used in the same element 
is it a problem?

Comment: Please extract the minimum related part and try make a demo on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

You should probably bind the handler when the page loads.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(
     $(elem).focusout(function (){

         if(!$(elem).val() || $(elem).val()==" "){
             alert("This Field can't be empty");     
         }
     });
);
```

**EDIT**: If you want to use it for multiple text fields, then you just have to modify your function like so:

```
function check(elem){
    if(!elem.data.val() || elem.data.val()==" "){
        alert("This Field can't be empty");     
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
$(document).ready(
    // Input element 1
    $(elem1).focusout($(elem1), check);

    // Input element 2
    $(elem2).focusout($(elem2), check);

);
```

Here's a JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/CgP2X/40/

**NOTE**: I am not proficient in jQuery, so I tried it first in fiddle. Sorry for the late edit.

Comment: I can't use like this, i have to use the same function for multiple elements